# implement PIVOT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

Hi I am a Java programmer and working on project with MySQL Db. as per the requirement I need to implement below SQL in MySQL. The SQL contain PIVOT functionality but MySQL does not support pivot. Is there any way I can convert my below SQL in MYSQL to achieve output?

```
INSERT INTO Fh Select D1, [X] as D2_X, [Y] as D2_Y 
FROM (SELECT D1 , D2, A From F) as p 
PIVOT (SUM (A) For D2 IN ([X], [Y])) as pvt
```

Comment: Yes, just take one of the million examples on this site. There's this search function on the top right of the page.

Comment: Can any one review the following query which I understood by examples INSERT INTO FH
SELECT 
 D1,  
 SUM(IF (D2 = '[X]'), A, 0 ) As [X],
 SUM(IF (D2 = '[Y]'), A, 0 ) As [Y],
From F
 Group by D1

Comment: INSERT INTO FH
SELECT 
 D1,  
 SUM(IF (D2 = '[X]', A, 0 )) As [X],
 SUM(IF (D2 = '[Y]', A, 0 ) ) As [Y]
From F
 Group by D1

Comment: Looks good, why don't you just verify it with your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT INTO FH SELECT D1, SUM(IF (D2 = '[X]', A, 0 )) As [X], SUM(IF (D2 = '[Y]', A, 0 ) ) As [Y] From F Group by D1